# Fixed point property of "3-star"

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X = (I_1\sqcup I_2 \sqcup I_3)/(0_1 \sim 0_2\sim0_3),(I_i=[0,1]_i)$.
I spend much time to trying to prove that any continuous map $X\to X$ have fixed point, but with no results..

Comment: Any contractible compact space has the fixed point property, by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.

Comment: @MikeMiller but i did't know about method which used to prove that theorem, so i think there is much simpler proof for this. (I'm sorry for my english)

Comment: @Mike: that's not quite right; the Lefschetz fixed point theorem as stated e.g. on Wikipedia requires the additional hypothesis of trianguability, and in the generality you've stated it, it doesn't hold (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @QiaochuYuan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ fixes $0$, we're done. Otherwise, $f$ sends zero into the interior of one of the legs, WLOG into the interior of $I_1$. If $f(I_1)$ intersects $0$, then the two paths $f(I_1)$ and $I_1$ must cross somewhere between $f(0)$ and $0$ by the IVT, so there is a fixed point somewhere in $I_1$. If $f(I_1)$ doesn't intersect $0$, then $f(I_1) \subseteq I_1$, and we're reduced to showing that any continuous map $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ has a fixed point. This also follows by IVT, and so there is again a fixed point in $I_1$.

Comment: I think the proof generalizes without too much difficulty to the case that $X$ is a finite tree - you can perform an induction on the number of edges - but it got a bit annoying to write out.

Comment: In case $f(I_1)$ intersects 0, why we can use IVT?
Let $p  \in f^{-1}(0)$ such $|[0,p]|$ is minimum(since $f^{-1}(0)$ closed). And i want to prove that $f([0,p]) \subset [0,f(0)]$ but i can't;(

Comment: If $d' \in I_2$ and $f^{-1}(d')$ is not empty therefore we can choose minimal $d$ such $f(d) = d'$. $f^{-1}[0,d'] = [d,p]$(is this correct?) therefore $f[0,d] \ni f(0),d'$ but $\not \ni 0$ therefore image of connected set is disconnected. I don't sure in correctness. (I'm sorry for my english)